# How to limit max char in ValueConverter

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I limit the number of characters in this `TextBlock`?
E.g.: It can only show up to 5 characters.

```xaml
<TextBlock >
    <Run Text="Tender Amount:"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding TenderAmount, 
                Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, 
                ConverterParameter='{}{0:C}'}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Here's the Code in my Converter

```
public sealed class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (parameter == null)
            return value;

        return string.Format((string)parameter, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public sealed class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (parameter == null)
            return value;

        var result = string.Format((string)parameter, value);

        if (MaxLength > 0)
            result = result.Substring(0, MaxLength);

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Where you declare your converter resource, do this:

```
<stuff:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter" MaxLength="5" />
```

Comment: Thank You , but im getting an MaxLength is not recognized or not accessible when i assign that in my resource

Comment: Make sure you re-compile the project that has the converter in it otherwise the xaml parser won't know the new property is there.

Comment: what do you mean re-compile?

Comment: Build the project that has your converter in it so it picks up the new property in the XAML editor. Also make sure you are setting `MaxLength` where you declare the resource, not where you reference it via `{StaticResource }`